# Issue populating fields in gatsby-source-strapi

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I am having an issue when trying to populate the fields in the gatsby graphql when using the gatsby-source-strapi plugin.

If I check the graph on strapi I can see all the fields fine but when populating these in gatsby I am only getting the ids no other fields.

I am using a component that has a relationship with the collection, this is my query in strapi that returns fine:

```
{
  "data": {
    "slideshows": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "13",
          "attributes": {
            "slideshow_set": [
              {
                "id": "505",
                "slideshow_slide": {
                  "data": {
                    "id": "886",
                    "attributes": {
                      "slide_image": {
                        "data": {
                          "attributes": {
                            "size": 21.1
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "506",
                "slideshow_slide": {
                  "data": {
                    "id": "887",
                    "attributes": {
                      "slide_image": {
                        "data": {
                          "attributes": {
                            "size": 16.07
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
```

on the gatsby side I get the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStrapiSlideshow": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "strapi_id": 13,
          "slideshow_set": [
            {
              "strapi_id": 505
            },
            {
              "strapi_id": 506
            },
..
```

Why am I only getting IDs and not ther fields?

Tried updating the gatsby-config.js with populate options for the fields but it doesn't help:

```
{
            singularName: "slideshow",
            queryParams: {
              populate: {
                slideshow_set: {
                  populate: {
                    title: "*",
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            pluginOptions: {
              i18n: {
                locale: "all",
              },
            },
          }
```